# Angular 6 production build throwing Syntax Errors

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a project that runs fine & also when I ran the command `ng build--prod` it complies successfully & I get the dist folder in my project. Now I have xammp installed on my machine so I copied that folder & pasted in the `htdocs` folder. So now I can access that folder as localhost/dist but the app throws the below errors & app is not running. Can any one tell me whats the problem exactly.

```
   GET http://localhost/styles.34c57ab7888ec1573f9c.css 404 (Not Found)
   GET http://localhost/main.d3384476e7e827a9f05c.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: you can define the base url in index.html and other thing is you can provide full path in index.html eg. C/xampp/folder/dist/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `baseUrl` is `/` hence it starts looking for resources in the root folder. 
You have two possible solutions.

1. Deploy angular application in the root folder.
2. Specify the base URL. you can specify base URL in `index.html` manually as 
   in `head` tag
   `<base href="dist/">`
   Or you can specify it on the time of building angular-cli has a builtin switch `--base-href`

   E.g: 
   `ng build --prod --base-href /dist/`

   For more information refer to angular-cli [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 6, you can specify the baseHref and deployUrl in "angular.json" config.

```
    {
      ...
      "projects": {
        "project-name": {
          ...
          "architect": {
            "build": {
              "options": {
                "baseHref": "/dist/",
                "deployUrl": "/dist",
                ...
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

In this way, you don't have to modify your index.html and also don't need to input extra params in command line to build your app.

Comment: In this way, dev build will also be running with `"baseHref": "/dist/"` is there a way to specify it in only for production configurations?

Comment: Isn't it a good practice to keep dev and prod environment consistent, so that you don't need to worry about something works in dev but not in prod?

Answer (score 0):

1) ng build --prod

2) index.html should be like that.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>App</title>
  <base href="">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

3) Copy from dist folder and you can put any server and run.

4) To view result call like eg. http://localhost:80/app